# GCE running Bottle stops listening to http requests

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, bottle

I have a very simple bottle application running on a GCE server (A simple ping-pong server):

```
import bottle

@bottle.route('/ping')
def ping():
    return 'pong'

SERVER_PORT = 5000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bottle.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = SERVER_PORT)
```

I can send pings and get pongs as expected, but if I let it sit for a while (the amount of time changes) and send a ping again, I see no indication that the server gets the request, and the request times out without an answer.

My server is running Ubuntu with Python3.6, and I'm using `screen` to keep the server alive when the ssh connection is broken.

Here is what I tried so far:

- The real application is way more complicated. I narrowed it down to the above example to make sure it's really bottle and not anything else that makes the server hang.
- I thought it might be related to the amount of requests (maybe I don't free some resource and after N requests don't have the resources to get the request), but the number of requests before the server stops answering varies
- I though it might be a timeout issue of some sort, but the amount of time between last answered request and the request that hangs changes (sometimes it will answer after 40 minutes, sometimes it won't)

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** The request does seem to hang at the server: when I'm sending a ping and waiting for a response, if I kill the server app while I'm waiting I'll immediately get a "page not found" page. But bottle doesn't recognise the request for some reason.

Comment: what url are you trying to access? is there any WSGI or gunicorn running this app?

Comment: I'm just accessing the server's static i.p.: http://123.45.67.890:5000/ping, and letting bottle handle all the comunication

Comment: is firewall up? is the server port 5000 open for access? to verify netstat -an | grep :5000

Comment: port 5000 is indeed open - as I said I can access it when I'm just launching the script, the problem starts after a while, with nothing changing in the GCE settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was caused by bottle's default HTTP development server.
Changing the server to `cherrypy` solved the issue (and made my app respond a lot faster).

```
import bottle

@bottle.route('/ping')
def ping():
    return 'pong'

SERVER_PORT = 5000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bottle.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = SERVER_PORT, server = 'cherrypy')
```